# Better and a Faster way to read a string from a URL

Tags: java, url

I am using this code to read content from a given URL. Is there and faster and better way to do it?

```
private static String readUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        int read;
        char[] chars = new char[1024];
        while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
            buffer.append(chars, 0, read); 

        return buffer.toString();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is 'better'? (faster? less verbose? best practices?)

Comment: better in the performance , less execution time

Comment: The code you've posted has nothing to do with JSON, and it does no parsing: What you're really asking is for a fast way to download a string from a given URL, right?

Comment: your code is ok. I'm guessing if there are performance problems then they are either in generating the JSON on the server or in processing it on the client, but not in actually reading it

Comment: yes , I need to read the String from the URL to parse it but is this a good way to download the String from the URL ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`

Comment: this will help a lot or just a little ?

Comment: It will be a tiny little bit faster. From the `StringBuilder` javadoc: This class provides an API compatible with StringBuffer, but with no guarantee of synchronization. This class is designed for use as a drop-in replacement for StringBuffer in places where the string buffer was being used by a single thread (as is generally the case). **Where possible, it is recommended that this class be used in preference to StringBuffer as it will be faster under most implementations**.

Comment: Thanks mochael667 but I am looking for a better than tiny little bit faster ;) , any ideas ?

Comment: The only thing you can improve in that part of the code that you posted is a better network connection ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Is this an HTTP URL? If yes, then you

- *must* look at the `Content-Type` header and ensure that you're
  applying a correct encoding to the stream. As it is, you're applying the default encoding
  of your particular JVM installation, which may not correspond to what the server is sending
- *should* look at the `Content-Length` header to pre-size your buffer.

Other than those two changes, there's not much opportunity to speed up bytes across the network.

Edit: you could also use Jakarta Commmons [IOUtils.toString()](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) to read the stream. This will reduce the amount of code that you have to write (and may be presumed fully debugged). However, it will have to resize buffers along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are libs / source available online that will do this for you:

http://json.org/java/

Comment: Oh well, no I mean the code you have is fine for reading from the URL, but it has nothing to do with JSON. You'll just get a big string that contains JSON. Sorry I might have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "BufferedReader.readLine()"